# Adding active state to menu with individual IDs

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

I have a page with a menu that uses individual ids for styling. the pages are loaded dynamically with ajax, so the menu php site is always the same. the problem is that I want to use active states for these IDs in the menu. how could I do that with php or javascript? all tutorials I saw for this just used one single class.

```
<nav>
   <ul class="navi">
     <li><a id="menu1" href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu2" href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu3" href="page3.php">Page 3</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu4" href="page4.php">Page 4</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu5" href="page5.php">Page 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
a#menu1 {
  color: #999794;
  width: 73px;
  height: 28px;
}
a#menu1:hover {
  background-image: url(Photos.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 73px;
  height: 28px;
}
a#menu1:active {
  background-image: url(Photos.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 73px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to place your css file in the footer of your page,  after ajax call

Answer (score 0):

On click of each link if you are dynamically loading the page , then witin the javascript after your ajax call

try this :

```
  $("#menu1").css({"background-image":"url(Photos.png)","background-repeat":"no-repeat","padding-top":"5px","margin-top":"-5px","width":"73px","height":"28px"});
```

or

```
  $(this).css({"background-image":"url(Photos.png)","background-repeat":"no-repeat","padding-top":"5px","margin-top":"-5px","width":"73px","height":"28px"});
```